# Why most of ROLL calculation formula from ACC doesn't implement MIU (u)

Tags: c

I've found that most of formula used to calculate ROLL have this form:

```
Roll = atan2( sqrt(Y*Y + X*X), Z) * 180/M_PI;
Roll = atan2( Y, Z) * 180/M_PI;
Roll = atan2( Y, sqrt(Z*Z+X*X));
```

Without changes in sing and without multiply X with miu like this:

```
Roll  = atan2( Y,   sign* sqrt(Z*Z+ miu*X*X));
sign  = 1 if accZ>0, -1 otherwise 
miu = 0.001
```

As specified from "freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN3461.pdf".

Why that?

It's becouse they make assumption before perform calculation or becouse miu add error on angle?

Comment: Perhaps no sign change is necessary because `atan2` returns an angle in the range –π to +π. Note there are several questions on Stackoverflow about calculating roll, pitch and yaw.

Comment: Your document says that `μ` is used to prevent the denominator being `0` in calculations. But `atan2` takes the numerator and denominator as separate arguments, for that reason.